# How to configure super linter on GitHub for all branches

Tags: github, github-actions, super-linter

Currently I have this file to check for linting errors when a PR is created on GitHub, but it targets only a single branch i.e *branch_name* and I have to change the branch name for every branch, how can I configure this to run on the branch that the PR is currently targeting?

I have tried to use pattern matching by using ** as described [here](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#filter-pattern-cheat-sheet) but that doesn't work.

```
name: Lint Code Base

on:
  pull_request:
    branches: [branch_name]

jobs:
  build:
    name: Lint Code Base
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout Code
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0

      - name: Lint Code Base
        uses: github/super-linter@v4
        env:
          VALIDATE_ALL_CODEBASE: false
          DEFAULT_BRANCH: branch_name
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          DISABLE_ERRORS: true
          
          PYTHON_FLAKE8_CONFIG_FILE: .flake8
          VALIDATE_PYTHON_FLAKE8: true
```

Comment: I don't quite understand: do you want to run on the code that currently lives on the base branch of the pull request (example: you open a PR from `feature` into `main`; you want to lint on `main`), or do you want to trigger the workflow no matter what branch you're opening the PR into?

Comment: If you don't want to exclude on any branch, you can simply omit the `branches` object.

Comment: If you want to run on the base branch, you have to use the `pull_request_target` event.

Comment: @BenjaminW. I want to run it on any branch, so for example if I open a PR from my fork to merge into "branch_name" this file works fine, but if I open a PR to "some_other_branch" this file won't work because that branch's name is not listed here. I want a setting under the "branches:" and "DEFAULT_BRANCH" parameters which will enable this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To trigger on any PR, and have super-linter run for the diff between the head branch and the base branch of the PR, you have to

1. not filter the `pull_request` on any branches, and
2. set the `DEFAULT_BRANCH` environment variable to the base branch of the PR.

Arguably, `DEFAULT_BRANCH` isn't a great name for that variable, because it's used to build the list of changed files, and PRs can be opened into branches other than the default branch of a repository.

Additionally:

- you should use the latest version of the checkout action: as of today, it's v4.1.1
- super-linter has moved into its own organization, and the action is now maintained at super-linter/super-linter
- I like pinning my runner version so it doesn't magically change (and break) one day, but that's a personal preference
- I don't think `fetch-depth: 0` is necessary, but the super-linter README recommends it anyway

Taken all together:

```yaml
name: Lint Code Base

on: pull_request

jobs:
  build:
    name: Lint Code Base
    runs-on: ubuntu-22.04

    steps:
      - name: Checkout Code
        uses: actions/checkout@v4.1.1
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0

      - name: Lint Code Base
        uses: super-linter/super-linter@v5.6.1
        env:
          VALIDATE_ALL_CODEBASE: false
          DEFAULT_BRANCH: ${{ github.event.pull_request.base.ref }}
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          DISABLE_ERRORS: true
          
          PYTHON_FLAKE8_CONFIG_FILE: .flake8
          VALIDATE_PYTHON_FLAKE8: true
```